# RichTextBox SelectionFont change back

Tags: c#, forms

I create RichTextBox and I got this code:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
richTextBox1.Text += "ddddd";
```

The text stay the same. I notice that richTextBox1.Text change my font back to the default font.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AppendText method:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
richTextBox1.AppendText("ddddd");

richTextBox1.SelectionFont = myDefaultFont;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = myDefaultColor;
```